# Yield Return equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, yield

I am writing down a view in SQL server (DWH) and the use case pseudo code is:

```
-- Do some calculation and generate #Temp1
-- ... contains other selects

-- Select statement 1
SELECT * FROM Foo
JOIN #Temp1 tmp on tmp.ID = Foo.ID
WHERE Foo.Deleted = 1

-- Do some calculation and generate #Temp2
-- ... contains other selects

-- Select statement 2
SELECT * FROM Foo
JOIN #Temp2 tmp on tmp.ID = Foo.ID
WHERE Foo.Deleted = 1
```

The result of the view should be:

```
Select Statement 1
UNION
Select Statement 2
```

The intended behavior is the same as the `yield return`in C#. Is there a way to tell the view which `SELECT` statements are actually part of the result and which are not? since the small calculations preceding what I need also contain selects.

Thank you!

Comment: A view consist of a *single* SELECT statement. Did you actually mean *stored procedure* instead of *view*?

Comment: Not true, you can execute the same code both in a view and in a stored procedure. As long as you use UNION, EXCEPT, INTERSECT etc.. you can use multiple SELECT

Comment: Yes, but I meant that in a wider sense, i.e. including a SELECT statement with UNION et al. (Incidentally, that would still constitute a *single* SQL statement.) What confused me (and made me comment in the first place) was this sentence: `Is there a way to tell the view which SELECT statements are actually part of the result and which are not?`. So I thought I'd clarify that bit.

Comment: Well, to do it right that should go into a stored procedure correct. Except because of security, end users have restricted db_reader roles with access to views only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better work around. It might be helpful for someone else. It is actually to include all the calculation inside `WITH` statements instead of doing them in the view core:

```
WITH Temp1 (ID)
AS
(
    -- Do some calculation and generate #Temp1
    -- ... contains other selects
)

, Temp2 (ID)
AS
(
    -- Do some calculation and generate #Temp2
    -- ... contains other selects
)

-- Select statement 1
SELECT * FROM Foo
JOIN Temp1 tmp on tmp.ID = Foo.ID
WHERE Foo.Deleted = 1

UNION

-- Select statement 2
SELECT * FROM Foo
JOIN Temp2 tmp on tmp.ID = Foo.ID
WHERE Foo.Deleted = 1
```

The result will be of course the `UNION` of all the outiside `SELECT` statements.

Comment: By the way, the "WITH" statement you mention is called a common table expression (CTE).  One little gotcha that often trips people up is that the statement immediately before the CTE must end in a semi-colon (a semi-colon is a statement terminator in SQL.  People often leave them out in T-SQL because they're optional - except for the statement immediately before a CTE where they're required.)

Comment: @SimonTewsi unless your script actually starts with `WITH` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yield return in C# returns rows one at a time as they appear in some underlying function.  This concept does not exist in SQL statements.  SQl is set-based, returning the entire result set, conceptually as a unit.  (That said, sometimes queries run slowly and you will see rows returned slowly or in batches.)

You can control the number of rows being returns using `TOP` (in SQL Server).  You can select particular rows to be returned using `WHERE` statements.  However, you cannot specify a `UNION` statement that conditionally returns rows from some components but not others.

The closest you may be able to come is something like:

```
if UseTable1Only = 'Y'
    select *
    from Table1
else if UseTable2Only = 'Y'
    select *
    from Table2
else
    select *
    from table1
    union
    select *
    from table2
```

You can do something similar using dynamic SQL, by constructing the statement as a string and then executing it.