# How to return partial result of a procedure during its calculation?

Tags: sql-server

How to return partial result of a procedure during its calculation in MS SQL? Let's say it takes a lot to calculate a procedure because of `waitfor delay` or a huge query inside. But I would like to show the results that are already calculated before the whole procedure reaches the end.

In the example below I would like to see "1" as a partial result before 5 seconds pass and I can see "2" as the final result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #Proc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS PartialResult;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

    SELECT 2 AS FinalResult;
END;

EXEC #Proc;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yield Return equivalent in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290847/yield-return-equivalent-in-sql-server)

Comment: That isn't how SQL works. If the SP is slow, perhaps you need to performance tune it.

Comment: @Cid, I think not. I would like to see both 1 and 2, only than I'd like to see 1 before 2 even starts being calculated.

Comment: @musialmi then split this into 2 procedures, and call the first, then the second

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this to present data to an application? If so, you could look at paging, so you are not returning such a big set.

Comment: Note that with a sufficiently large result set, the procedure *will* be streaming the rows of the first query to the client *without* waiting for everything else to have completed. It is not the case that all data is buffered until the procedure reaches the end. The `RAISERROR` buffer flushing trick that Martin illustrates below is useful if you have a small result set and/or `PRINT` statements you want flushed  and/or you're using Management Studio. A "large" query may simple fail to return any results until a large amount of time has passed (due to a sort step, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Add a `RAISERROR('',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;` to flush the buffer to the client before the delay.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #Proc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS PartialResult;

    RAISERROR('',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

    SELECT 2 AS FinalResult;
END;
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you! However, I would be interested if it's possible to both print 1 to the user and return 2 as the final result so that I can run `INSERT INTO #Table EXEC #Proc` and both see 1 and have 2 saved into #Table.
I'm sorry I didn't write it earlier.

Comment: @musialmi - you would need to `PRINT 1` it not `SELECT 1` then

Comment: @musialmi: in the case of multiple rows you cannot print the results of a query directly, though, nor "show" a result set but not actually "return" it to the client for debugging purposes. If you need something like that you'd have to insert the results into a different table altogether and inspect that from another session. Such an operation is not free, so if it's only for debugging you'd want to disable it for production.